# How do I backup/restore contacts on Windows Mobile without ActiveSync?

Tags: windows-mobile

I'd like to be able to backup and restore telephone contact numbers from a Windows CE device. I had a brief look at [ActiveSync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activesync), but I don't want to install Outlook or Exchange or to store the data with a third party ([like using Google](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138636)). [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) files have served me well for all my old phones.

Are there applications and/or simple techniques for reading the contact information?

- Device: Samsung SGH-i900V; Windows Mobile 6.1 Professional
- Target OS: Windows XP

Comment: Great Question. Its one of my need too.  I would like to keep a close watch on this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PIM Backup](http://www.dotfred.net).

[image]

backup windows mobile deviceEnter PPCPIMBackup. This tiny little program, with its itsy-bitsy little footprint, does everything you need in a PIM backup solution. Scheduling, an intuitive and simple interface, and the level of depth to name a few; it has all the options you could think of for a PIM backup and more. After all is said and done it will give you a single small file with your data in it.

Source:

> http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/backup-your-windows-mobile-without-activesync/

Comment: This app is pretty good and can produce a ZIP of UTF-16 encoded text files; one caveat is that it will export Outlook contacts, but not contacts on the SIM, so I'm holding out to see if anyone has any other suggestions. Direct link for manual and older versions: http://www.dotfred.net/

Comment: neat, the only thing it seems to fail is MMS (or at least their attachments)